# Getting the prime numbers till 10000 in fortran?

Tags: fortran, primes

Im trying to print prime numbers till 10000. (display the first five for testing)
This is my program

```
program primes
    implicit none
    
    integer :: array(1229)
    integer :: i, ind
    logical :: is_prime
    ind = 1
    do i = 2, 10000, 1
        if (is_prime(i) .eqv. .true.) then
            array(ind) = i
            ind = ind + 1
        end if
    end do
    
    print *, array(1)
    print *, array(2)
    print *, array(3)
    print *, array(4)
    print *, array(5)
end program primes

function is_prime(n) result(ispr)
    implicit none
    
    integer :: c, i
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    logical :: ispr

    c = 0
    do i = 2, n
        if (mod(i,2) == 0) then
            c = c + 1
        end if
    end do
    
    ispr = (c == 0)
    
end function is_prime
```

I don't know why but this is the output

```
     9175178
     6417360
     5374044
     6750309
     7536745
```

Why does this happen and how to correct?

Comment: I really don't understand your is_prime function. Shouldn't  it be `mod(n,i) == 0` and `ispr = (c == 1)`

Comment: found an online fortran compiler :  https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_fortran_compiler, works with the suggest changes...

Comment: Also better wouild be to avoid using an external function for is_prime - best is to use a module subprogram, or, in a short program like this, an internal subprogram

Comment: One way to debug a program is to add print statements at various places. This can show you where programs branch, and what values of variables are. `if (is_prime(i) .eqv. .true.) then  array(ind) = i   ind = ind + 1  print *,i," prime" else print *, i, " not prime`"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is_prime should be(n is the only divider of n besides 1 <=> c == 1)

```
function is_prime(n) result(ispr)
    implicit none
    
    integer :: c, i
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    logical :: ispr

    c = 0
    do i = 2, n
        if (mod(n,i) == 0) then
            c = c + 1
        end if
    end do
    
    ispr = (c == 1)
    
end function is_prime
```

Could be optimezed by leaving the loop when c == 1 and i < n(after adding 1 to c)...

See on [online fortran compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/lwrYVgNrh)

[version with exit loop](https://onlinegdb.com/pxdiJS3Vl)

Answer (score 2):

While I am not familiar with modern Fortran, it looks to me as if `function is_prime(n) result(ispr)` is not working.

In the `do` loop in that function, you want a loop that tests thus:

- is `n` divisible by 2?
- is `n` divisible by 3?
- is `n` divisible by 4?
- is `n` divisible by 5?

and so on.

But, what it is *actually* doing is asking these:

- is 2 divisible by 2?
- is 3 divisible by 2?
- is 4 divisible by 2?
- is 5 divisible by 2?

and so on.

As a result, your counter will always have a non-zero value, and your function will always return `false`.

But, that's not the only problem. From your results, it looks like your Fortran implementation does not automatically initialize variables. Suppose I have statements like the following:

```
integer :: b
print *,b
```

What will be the result?

Remember, the names of variables represent locations in the computer's memory. If a variable is not initialized, it's value will be what was in the memory location before your program started to run. This value will not be related to your program.

I have 2 suggestions to fix the 2nd problem:

1. Prior to `do i = 2, 10000, 1`, have another loop that sets each value in `array`.
2. Set a values of each `array (i)` inside your `do i = 2, 10000, 1` loop. One way to do this is to set one value when `(is_prime(i) .eqv. .true.)` is `true` and a different value when it is `false`.

Comment: Some languages automatically 'zero out' variables at the start of a program. Some don't. One place where I used to work, it was an option. If we wanted it, we would insert `$CONTROL INIT` in front of the source code.

Comment: Even better is to test for a factor of 2 explicitly and then test odd factors: 3, 5, 7, 9, ... up to the square root of the number.

Comment: @James 'A positive integer cannot have a prime factor larger than its square root.' This sentence is clearly wrong, sqrt(22) is 4 something and its prime factors are 2 and 11.
The truth is, you won't have to check anymore, since if you haven't found one yet, you won't find one > sqrt(n).